# SVM plot R library(e1071)

Tags: r, plot, svm

I'm working with a data set that has more than 500 variables, all of them numeric.

I've run the `svm()` function of the `e1071` library and the results are great.

Now I'm struggling with the way to plot my results.

I had reviewed some the `plot.svm` function, and I can make it work with 4 variables.

But I'm wondering if there is a better way for plotting my results, something that summarizes the model I have created with svm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are too many ways to plot your results to tell.  Maybe if you gave a sample and an idea of the type of plot you want..

Comment: Thank you Nathan. What I'm looking for is some approach that allows me to plot in 2D or 3D a summary of the results of svm according to the output variable of the formula of my model. I know this is kind of "diffuse" but I'm pretty new in SVM and don't know where to start. Thanks